# Biber 2.8 and 2.9 fail to download from remote location and missing SSLeay module

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, miktex, texstudio, biber

Biber 2.8 and 2.9 seem to fail to fetch the remote source for me on Windows 10 with this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource[location=remote]{https://www.dropbox.com/s/l772znk922oyabe/example_ref.bib?dl=1}
\begin{document}
Some citation \cite{Nobody17}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The error it produces is

```
Process started: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\biber.exe"  "document"

Can't load 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4a61636f62\cache-02947398048c143181ebb9c4e483433d2665ac35\4a65cefc.xs.dll' for module Net::SSLeay: load_file:The specified module could not be found at /loader/HASH(0x6b1158)/DynaLoader.pm line 193.

INFO - This is Biber 2.9 (**same thing on 2.8**)
INFO - Logfile is 'document.blg'
INFO - Reading 'document.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/l772znk922oyabe/example_ref.bib?dl=1' for section 0
INFO - Data source 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/l772znk922oyabe/example_ref.bib?dl=1' is a remote BibTeX data source - fetching ...

Process exited with error(s)
```

The error makes me think it has something to do with SSLeay and possibly the update to 2.8/2.9 (although I haven't ruled out a HTTP request).

*Can't load '...' for module Net::SSLeay ... The specified module could not be found ...*

The error doesn't occur for me when using Biber 2.7 and BibLaTeX 3.7:

```
Process started: biber.exe "document"

INFO - This is Biber 2.7
INFO - Logfile is 'document.blg'
INFO - Reading 'document.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/l772znk922oyabe/example_ref.bib?dl=1' for section 0
INFO - Data source 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/l772znk922oyabe/example_ref.bib?dl=1' is a remote BibTeX data source - fetching ...
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\iAAH5MlBHD\biber_remote_data_source_i_vnI.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Sorting list 'nty/global/' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nty' and locale 'en-US'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
INFO - Writing 'document.bbl' with encoding 'ascii'
INFO - Output to document.bbl

Process exited normally
```

Is this caused by the recent update to Biber 2.8/2.9 (and corresponding BibLaTeX update) or from some other problem?

**Update:**
Here is a more detailed error log:

```
>biber document.bcf
INFO - This is Biber 2.8
INFO - Logfile is 'document.blg'
INFO - Reading 'document.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/l772znk922oyabe/example_ref.bib?dl=1' for section 0
INFO - Data source 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/l772znk922oyabe/example_ref.bib?dl=1' is a remote BibTeX data source - fetching ...
Can't load 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4a61636f62\cache-4b419f4e7b1e3e9cdb78a8c63410aec04e2636e8\bbb0be1a.xs.dll' for module Net::SSLeay: load_file:The specified module could not be found at /loader/HASH(0x260c624)/DynaLoader.pm line 193.
  at /loader/HASH(0x2a210fc)/PAR/Heavy.pm line 78.
Compilation failed in require at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4a61636f62\cache-4b419f4e7b1e3e9cdb78a8c63410aec04e2636e8\inc\lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4a61636f62\cache-4b419f4e7b1e3e9cdb78a8c63410aec04e2636e8\inc\lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 19.
Compilation failed in require at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4a61636f62\cache-4b419f4e7b1e3e9cdb78a8c63410aec04e2636e8\inc\lib/Net/HTTPS.pm line 25.
Can't load 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4a61636f62\cache-4b419f4e7b1e3e9cdb78a8c63410aec04e2636e8\e5d86be9.xs.dll' for module Crypt::SSLeay: load_file:The specified module could not be found at /loader/HASH(0x260c624)/DynaLoader.pm line 193.
  at /loader/HASH(0x2a210fc)/PAR/Heavy.pm line 78.
Compilation failed in require at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4a61636f62\cache-4b419f4e7b1e3e9cdb78a8c63410aec04e2636e8\inc\lib/Net/SSL.pm line 20.
Compilation failed in require at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4a61636f62\cache-4b419f4e7b1e3e9cdb78a8c63410aec04e2636e8\inc\lib/Net/HTTPS.pm line 29.
Compilation failed in require at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4a61636f62\cache-4b419f4e7b1e3e9cdb78a8c63410aec04e2636e8\inc\lib/LWP/Protocol/https.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4a61636f62\cache-4b419f4e7b1e3e9cdb78a8c63410aec04e2636e8\inc\lib/Biber/Input/file/bibtex.pm line 185.
```

**Update 2:**
Following [moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe)'s [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403360/biber-2-8-and-2-9-fail-to-download-from-remote-location-and-missing-ssleay-modul?noredirect=1#comment1005060_403360), clearing the cache given by `biber --cache` did not fix the problem and the log produced using `biber --trace` doesn't seem to provide any more useful information. 32bit and 64bit Biber both fail.

**Update 3:**
[I've now started an issue over on GitHub](https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/200).

**Update 4:**
I have reproduced the error on another two completely different computers (three altogether). Two Windows 10 PCs and a Windows 7 PC running on two completely different local area networks.

To reproduce the error:

1. Update to Biber 2.9 and BibLaTeX 3.9 packages using the MiKTeX 2.9 Package Manager.
2. Run PDFLaTeX on the MWE
3. Run Biber on the MWE
4. The error log above should be reproduced.

(A side note: On the Windows 7 PC I noticed a pop window on the first run which noted that `libcrypto-1_1-x64__.dll` was missing which is an OpenSSL DLL. This window hasn't popped up again since which is odd and adding the path to (an existing) `libcrypto-1_1-x64__.dll` as a Windows environment variable has not solved the problem.)

Comment: Works fine for me with biber 2.9 on mac.

Comment: Forgot to add that I'm running Windows 10 but good to know that it works fine for you on mac. I just tested Biber 2.8 and it also does not work for me, though, 2.8 was released recently too, right?

Comment: Works for me on Windows 10/MikTeX with Biber 2.9.

Comment: Try deleting the cache folder (you can find it by typing `biber --cache` into the CLI, if there are more `par-` folders in the directory delete them as well). The next run after that will take a bit longer.

Comment: If you compile with `biber --trace` you get a huge `.log`. Maybe some more info is hidden there. Check for the reported version of SSLeay and friends.

Comment: Cleared all the cache folders, ran `biber --trace` and checked the `.blg` (log) file. All to no avail. The log stops at `fetching ...`. Not sure where to check the SSLeay version?

Comment: I thought the `--trace` `.log` would report the SSLeay version, but it didn't. Mhhh. Does the version from https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/current/binaries/Windows/ work for you (check both 32 and 64 bit if you are on a 64 bit machine).

Comment: I had already checked both 32bit and 64bit versions, though, I neglected to mention that. Neither work on my 64bit machine, both give identical errors.

Comment: So just to recap: You have now tested both versions from sourceforge as well as the binary that comes with MikTeX and none of the three worked for you? They all fail with the same error?

Comment: Yep, I have tested the copy downloaded with MiKTeX and the two versions from Sourceforge, all give the same error. :(

Comment: I have no idea what is going on and can't reproduce the problem. Maybe you have more luck at the Biber bugtracker https://github.com/plk/biber/issues, perhaps PLK knows what is going on.

Comment: I'm looking through the changes related to SSL from Biber version 2.7 to 2.8, hopefully I find something. I'll post the issue on GitHub like you suggested, thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69369/discussion-between-jacobd-and-moewe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a [bug in Biber 2.8 and 2.9](https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/200) where a DLL reference to OpenSSL's `libcrypto-1_1_.dll` (32bit) and `libcrypto-1_1-x64__.dll` (64bit) was missing.

I have no idea how [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403360/biber-2-8-and-2-9-fail-to-download-from-remote-location-and-missing-ssleay-modul#comment1004963_403360) and [moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe) managed to get Biber 2.9 working (as commented above).

The **bug has been fixed in Biber 2.10 DEV** (the development version) and [made available over on SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/development/).

[This is the commit to the Biber repository which fixed the issue](https://github.com/plk/biber/commit/85ac9ff53c8275f36213c0f88443c7e383ea4bce).

Comment: I highly suspect it worked for me since I have StarwberryPerl installed. Maybe Biber picked up the correct DLL there.

Comment: Interesting. I also have Strawberry Perl installed on one of the OSs, though. I updated Strawberry Perl in the process of debugging this too because I thought that may have been the issue. I also added the DLLs to the system path after the updating of Strawberry Perl didn’t help.

Comment: Mhh, OK, if that can't be it then I have no idea how it worked for me.